# Calling a function that is not defined anywhere in the code?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

```
function Person(first,last,age) {
   this.firstname = first;
   this.lastname = last;
   this.age = age;
   var bankBalance = 7500;

   var returnBalance = function() {
      return bankBalance;
   };

  this.askTeller = function(){
      return returnBalance;
  }

}

var john = new Person('John','Smith',30);
console.log(john.returnBalance);
var myBalanceMethod = john.askTeller();
var myBalance = myBalanceMethod();
console.log(myBalance);
```

This is an example on code academy. I do not understand the

```
var myBalanceMethod = john.askTeller();
var myBalance = myBalanceMethod();
```

What i am thinking is that `var myBalanceMethod = john.askTeller();` sets the value of `myBalanceMethod` to `returnBalance`. Then I am not sure what , `var myBalance = myBalanceMethod();` does because `myBalanceMethod` is not actually a method, i dont think? Can someone please explain what is going on in these last lines of code

Answer (score 1):

myBalanceMethod is a method.

```
var myBalanceMethod = john.askTeller();
```

This line is setting a reference and that is likely what this code is demonstrating. myBalanceMethod becomes a function after being assigned to john.askTeller() which is a function.

To further demonstrate this, I can do the following:

```
function addNumbers(a, b) {
     return a + b;
}

var myRefObj = addNumbers;

alert(addNumbers(10,20));
alert(myRefObj(10,20));  // same answer
```

Answer (score 0):

`john.askTeller()` returns `returnBalance`, which is a function and is then assigned to `myBalanceMethod`; therefore `myBalanceMethod` is a function and can be invoked using `()` (you're invoking `returnBalance` inside `john` which is otherwise inaccessible).

```
var myBalanceMethod = john.askTeller(); // myBalanceMethod is now a reference to returnBalance in john
var myBalance = myBalanceMethod(); // returnBalance is executed and value (7500) assigned to myBalance
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. One more thing, when `var myBalance = myBalanceMethod();` is run does it return `"bankBalance"` or the value of `7500`

Comment: It returns `7500` and assigns it to `myBalance`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myBalanceMethod = john.askTeller();
```

The above will assign the returnBalance method to myBalanceMethod. Note that it did not have the open and closing parenthesis (). Meaning, it wont execute the function but will only assign. Thus, myBalanceMethod is now a function. Look at the code below:

```
this.askTeller = function(){
  return returnBalance;
}
```

Then,

```
var myBalance = myBalanceMethod();
```

myBalance was assigned the value returned by myBalanceMethod(). Note the (), so it executes the function. In your Person constructor, it returns the BankBalance which is 7500. So, myBalance is assigned 7500 value.

```
var returnBalance = function() {
  return bankBalance;
```

};